# What if(null) statement return in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, autoboxing

I have a `method` which has a `Boolean` `parameter`, like:

```
public void method(Boolean parameter){
...
}
```

Can I just use `if(parameter)` to determine the logic?
What if `parameter` is `null`?

Comment: you could try it out yourself(by the way your `method` should have a return type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will turn your

```
if (parameter)
```

into

```
if (parameter.booleanValue())
```

via auto-unboxing. So that should tell you what will happen with `null` (a `NullPointerException`, just like any other time you call a method on `null`).

Answer (score 2):

If you tried it, you'd see a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

But the [`Boolean.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#equals%28java.langObject%29) Javadoc does begin

> **Returns `true` if and only if the argument is not `null`** and is a Boolean object that represents the same boolean value as this object.

*(my emphasis)*

So you could do

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(parameter)) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

which I believe would handle your `null` case.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data type from `Boolean` to `boolean`.  `boolean` is a primitive data type and cannot be null.

Comment: Presumably there's some *reason* for using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: And `Boolean` is the wrapper class for `boolean` and can be null.

Comment: Possibly, but the OP also doesn't have a return type for his method.  One may assume that they're relatively new to Java anyway, and may not even know the difference.

Comment: Using Boolean or boolean would depend on the scenario. In this case also, it will depend on what is being done with a parameter. If it is just used in the if condition as shown, boolean would make more sense. In a case where it is being stored in a collection or used in a generic which would only allow objects, it may be more consistent to use Boolean.  So in your case, you might be safe from NPE if you use boolean as compiler won't allow passing null.